# Locally hosted website isn't routing correctly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, web, routes

I have a website I'm creating, still in it's beginning stages.  I have it hosted locally, but when I click the links, it says the files cannot be found even though they do in fact exist.  Also, the styling won't apply.  My index.html is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<base href="/">

<title>Sports</title>

<!-- CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- custom styles -->

<!-- JS -->
<script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
<script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/TeamsCtrl.js"></script>>
<script src="js/services/TeamsService.js"></script>
<script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="container">

<!-- HEADER -->
<nav class="container-fluid navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="HeaderController">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i>Sports</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav">
            <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/teams') }"><a href="/teams">Teams</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/login"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Log In</a></li>
        </ul>

</nav>

<!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
<div ng-view></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The part I do not understand is that this runs fine on my work computer.  I zipped it up, sent it to myself at home, and it doesn't run correctly.  When I click the Teams link, it takes me here:  **file:///C:/teams**, which isn't correct.  I have no idea where to even start looking, as this is my first web project.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as to where I should start/what the issue could be.  Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to run by opening local file and not running a `localhost` web server on local machine

Answer (score 0):

use `~` symbol infront of all your links. For example use `~/teams` instead of `/teams`.

`~` symbol will take you current folder where the files are located.

Comment: I just tried.  Now it's trying to send me to file:///C:/~/teams

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't running a localhost web server on my machine.  Once I did, everything worked fine.